# PHP regular expression for operators in C

Tags: php, regex

Hi I wanna count operators in C files with PHP like +,-,++,--,<<,>>,!=,*=,...etc
Is there a method to count it with regular expressions (something like ++ and + will count as 2 not 3) ?

Comment: regex? don't. it's not the right tool.

Comment: It really depends on how accurate you need to be.  The answer about using a lexical analyzer is correct if you truly need an exact count.  The regex answer below should work to get you a rough number, but it will suffer from false positives, as it will be providing a char or char pair count and not a true operator count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this regex:

```
(\+\+|--|==|>=|<=|!=|<<|>>|!=|\+=|-=|\*=|\/=|%=|\+|-|\*|%|=)
```

And then just count the number of matches.  Like so:

```
$code = file_get_contents("cfile.c");

preg_match_all("/(\+\+|--|==|>=|<=|!=|<<|>>|!=|\+=|-=|\*=|\/=|%=|\+|-|\*|%|=)/", $code, $matches);

$num_operators = count($matches[0]);
```

**Note:** If you also wanted to include the Logical Operators `&&`, `||`, `!` , then just add them to the end of the pattern, like so:

```
(\+\+|--|==|>=|<=|!=|<<|>>|!=|\+=|-=|\*=|\/=|%=|\+|-|\*|%|=|&&|\|\||!)
```

Comment: \b([+*%=-!]|[><!+*/%-]=|([<>+=&|-])\2))\b

Comment: first group is singles, second group is those followed by an = third group is doubles.  The third group may not work with some regex compilers as it uses an embedded back-reference.

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions simply aren't up to the job.

Consider the following code, for example:

```
/***************************************************************
 There are no multiplication or division operators in this file
 ***************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h> // No comparison operators either
#define _ -
int main() {
  int a=0,b=~6;
  printf("%s\n","Hello?"); // No modulus or ternary operators :-\
  a += b; // Not even an addition operator
  printf("a is still equal to %d\n",a); // See what I mean?
  a = a _ b _ b _ b _ b _ b _ b; // But there are 6 subtraction operators
  printf("The answer is %d\n",a); // Would your regex find those??
  return 0;
}
```

There are plenty of pitfalls in this file that would be very difficult to avoid with regular expressions. (And don't get me started on [trigraphs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs#C).)

To do this properly, you should first pass the source code through a preprocessor (like `gcc -E`) to strip away the comments and expand `#define` statements. After that, you would probably be better off using  a [lexical analyzer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lex_%28software%29) to parse the results.